# Table Paginator is not working as expected

Tags: json, angular

I am fetching the data from the server, the data is coming well and showing in the but the paginator is not working although it is only showing.

The paginator is showing the webpage but it is not working as the next button, go to page etc.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col my-3">
      <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <app-message></app-message>

        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">



          <!-- Position Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}}</td>
          </ng-container>

           <!-- Position Column -->
           <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.phone}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>

        <mat-paginator   [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the TS code.

```
 export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'phone'];

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>([]);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  constructor(public data: DataService, private rest: RestApiService) {}
   ngOnInit() {
   this.getUsers();
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  async getUsers(){
    try {

      const data =await this.rest.get("http://localhost:3030/user/auth/all/users");
      if(data['status']) {
        console.log(data['data']);

        this.dataSource = data['data'];

      } else {
        this.data.error(data['message']);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.data.error(error['message']);
    }
  }

}


interface PeriodicElement {
  slno:number,
  name: string,
  phone: string
}

const dataArray: PeriodicElement[] = [];
```

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz instance?

Comment: Sure, here is it - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t32suq

Comment: Paginator is showing but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u integrate AfterViewInit and call this

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

and change

```
this.dataSource = data['data'];
```

to

```
this.dataSource.data = data['data'];
```

Comment: Did u delete from constructor?

Comment: There is nothing inside constructor.

Comment: constructor(public data: DataService, private rest: RestApiService) {}
   ngOnInit() {
   this.getUsers();
   this.ngAfterViewInit();
  }

Comment: I edited answer u call  this.paginator.data in ngAfterIInit and  not in constructor and  after u get data from api change code such as I edited in answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Cagri, finally it works. Can you explain, why we to write dataSource.data, please ?

Comment: Because after u get data from api u will update just data of datasource not all datasource

Comment: You 're  welcome :) then can u check my answer as accepted if u solve your proble with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import `MatPaginator` from `@angular/material/paginator` not `@angular/material`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not added the corresponding table and paginator modules inside your app.module.ts

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';



import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatTableModule,MatPaginatorModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As your code was not working even on stackblitz, so i have added dummy data to show you an example. Please find stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcgvnu